# How to refresh a function every hour in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, refresh

I am trying to make a simple program that gets information off an API and displays it on python GUI with tkinter.
So far I have been able to do this but a new challenge is getting the information collected from the API to refresh every hour.
Basically I need the `data()` function to be re-run every hour so that the information on the GUI updates.

```
from tkinter import *
import requests

def data():
    url = requests.get("https://stats.foldingathome.org/api/donor/PointofHorizon")
    json = str((url.json()))

    i = json.count(',')
    data = json.split(",")

    score = data[i]
    score = score.replace(" 'credit': ","")
    score = score.replace("}","")

    unit = data[0]
    unit = unit.replace("{'wus': ","")

    scores = Label(app, text = score)
    units = Label(app, text =  unit)

    scores.pack()
    units.pack()    

app = Tk()
app.geometry("500x200")
title = Label(app,text = "Folding Score")
title.pack()
```

I have looked around and haven't been able to find a way that works for me, would be amazing if someone could point me in the right direction. I'm still learning and all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Waiting certain amount of time with Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51764757/waiting-certain-amount-of-time-with-tkinter)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011694/how-to-call-a-function-with-delay-in-tkinter.

Comment: As an aside, `import *` is generally bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the after method in tkinter. I changed the `data` function to refresh data on the widgets. I moved the code that created the labels to be outside of the refresh_data function. Once the widgets were created, I called the `refresh_data` function to put information on the widgets. This function would tell tkinter to wait an hour before running it again which created a loop.

```py
from tkinter import *
import requests

def refresh_data():
    url = requests.get("https://stats.foldingathome.org/api/donor/PointofHorizon")
    json = str((url.json()))

    i = json.count(',')
    data = json.split(",")

    score = data[i]
    score = score.replace(" 'credit': ","")
    score = score.replace("}","")

    unit = data[0]
    unit = unit.replace("{'wus': ","")

    scores.config(text=score)
    units.config(text=unit)

    app.after(3600000, refresh_data) #3600000 milliseconds in an hour

app = Tk()
app.geometry("500x200")
title = Label(app,text = "Folding Score")
title.pack()

scores = Label(app)
units = Label(app)


scores.pack()
units.pack()

refresh_data()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This answer would be a bit better if you took the time to explain what changes you made, so that the OP doesn't have to compare your code line-by-line and character-by-character to see what you changed.